# Why System error: StopUpstreamCommandsException is raised only from inside Invoke-Command when Select-Object -First 1?

Tags: powershell

Could somebody explain the below behaviour?

This script returns no error and works as I'd expect it to work:

```bsh
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    myProp = 'asd'
}          
$propVal = $obj | Select-Object -ExpandProperty myProp -First 1
'prop val 2: ' + $propVal
'No error here: ' + $error
```

If I wrap it in `Invoke-Command`, it outputs the below:

```
prop val 1: asd
"System error" from invoke command: System.Management.Automation.StopUpstreamCommandsException: System error.
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

Here's the full script producing the above output.

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {                          
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        myProp = 'asd'
    }          
    $propVal = $obj | Select-Object -ExpandProperty myProp -First 1
    'prop val 1: ' + $propVal
} -ErrorVariable err    
'"System error" from invoke command: ' + $err
```

I use PS version 5.1.

I'd really appreciate the explanation of:

1. why is `StopUpstreamCommandsException` raised?
2. why it's raised only when this script is wrapped in `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: Not that this explains anything, but if you capture the ```-ErrorVariable``` on the ```select-object``` in your first example you get the same error... ```$propVal = $obj | Select-Object -ExpandProperty myProp -First 1 -ErrorVariable selerr; write-host $selerr[0].ToString()```

Comment: and coincidentally, it looks like it's been fixed a few days ago in this commit... https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/commit/26c380de6edc402302a40cece7cc6d7f0b6e970d in this PR https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/10840

Comment: Thank you @mclayton, I think it explains everything. If you care to write an answer instead of a comment, then I'm definitely going to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments above, if you capture the error variable from `Select-Object` in your first example you'll see the same error:

```bsh
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    myProp = 'asd'
}
$propVal = $obj | Select-Object -ExpandProperty myProp -First 1 -ErrorVariable myerr
write-host $myerr[0].ToString()
```

outputs:

```
System.Management.Automation.StopUpstreamCommandsException: System error.
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

From this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9185), it looks like `StopUpstreamCommandsException` is a 'secret exception' used internally to tell upstream commands in a pipeline that no more input is required, but it's "leaking" out into the error variable in Select-Object.

It also looks like it's been fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/10840) for future versions of PowerShell, but that might not help you right now if you're using v5.1. In the meantime, just ignore the error and code around it if you can...